# What regex or command can I use to trim this output?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am trying to capture a specific output in a $ variable for my remote server configuration that will run commands one after another.

In an ubuntu environment that has pm2 node package installed, it comes with a command that will output something I need to run.

Command 1:

PM2=$(pm2 startup systemd)

Will output this string when I run echo $PM2:

```
[PM2] Init System found: systemd [PM2] You have to run this command as root. Execute the following command: sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u username --hp /home/username
```

I need to capture this exact output as a $var:

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u username --hp /home/username
```

So I can have my cloud init config file run it in the next command.

Command 2:

```
$PM2
```

How can I get $PM2 to only have the output value of

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u username --hp /home/username
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help :

```
pm2response=$(pm2 startup systemd) # Use lower case for user defined variables
${pm2response#*Execute the following command:} # Shell param expansion
```

But this assumes that your string has the phrase `Execute the following command:` in it though I guess I am right in assuming so. Good luck!

---

<sup>**Note :** More on SHELL Parameter Substitution [[ **here** ]](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)</sup>